# How to integrate cucumber with Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, cucumber, build.gradle, cucumber-jvm

I keep getting this error when i run my cucumber test from Jenkins. My test is perfectly fine when i run it from eclipse. what am i doing wrong in Jenkins?

[31mFailed scenarios:[0m
[31mGapLogin.feature:3 [0m# Scenario: Login to Gap

1 Scenarios ([31m1 failed[0m)
3 Steps ([31m1 failed[0m, [36m2 skipped[0m)
0m22.931s

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='_GAPLogin_WAR_GAPLoginportlet_:userregform:userid']"}
Command duration or timeout: 15.10 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
System info: host: 'B02176', ip: '10.105.129.9', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=.//*[@id='_GAPLogin_WAR_GAPLoginportlet_:userregform:userid']}
Session ID: af49b00e-63c7-4710-b253-04410d0a8b61
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=46.0}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:500)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at main.java.GapDefinition.LogintoGap(GapDefinition.java:27)
    at ?.Given I loged in To Gap website(GapLogin.feature:4)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='_GAPLogin_WAR_GAPLoginportlet_:userregform:userid']"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
System info: host: 'B02176', ip: '10.105.129.9', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at .FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/anonymous8675081044043132780webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
    at .fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/anonymous8675081044043132780webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:625)

:cucumber FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\GapLogin\workspace\build.gradle' line: 14
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':cucumber'.

  > Process 'command 'C:\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 28.997 secs
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is a NoSuchElementException. It is a Selenium exception. Selenium is unable to locate an element.

I would trouble shoot this issue from the perspective that your ci server is different from your local environment and Theresienstadt causing the problem.

Comment: but selenium was able to locate it both from eclipse and command prompt through build.gradle file. Am i not suppose to use the selenium stand alone server? thanks

Comment: The problem may be that the CI server is not allowed to reach the web page. Or that it, for some strange reason, sees another web page. There is a difference between your local environment and the CI server. You need to understand that difference before you are able to resolve your issue.